# Javascript date object Month conversion

Tags: javascript, date

I have a calendar widget where a user can select a date in the future and have the current time elapsed from then compared to todays date. Whenever a date is entered I have a small section where the `innerHTML` is changed to the elapsed time. However, my month conversion is not working. When I select a month in the future for example August. Rather than it inputting 2 months [x] amount of days it just prints 44 days. What am I doing wrong with my code?

```
function updateCountdown() {
   var dateToday = new Date();
   var dateFrom = Date.UTC(dateToday.getFullYear(), dateToday.getMonth(), dateToday.getDate(), dateToday.getHours(), dateToday.getMinutes(), dateToday.getSeconds());
   var dateTo = Date.UTC(dateObject.getFullYear(), dateObject.getMonth(), dateObject.getDate(), 0, 0, 0); // all launches at 8:00pm UTC

   if ((dateTo - dateFrom) < 1000) { // time will be less than 0 when setInterval runs next
      clearInterval(countdown);
      document.getElementById("countdownSection").style.display = "none";
   }

   //months
   var monthsUntil = Math.floor((dateTo - dateFrom) / 2880000);
   document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = " :" + monthsUntil + " months";

   // days
   var daysUntil = Math.floor((dateTo - dateFrom) / 86400000);
   document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = daysUntil + " days";

   // hours
   var fractionalDay = (dateTo - dateFrom) % 86400000;
   var hoursUntil = Math.floor(fractionalDay / 3600000);
   if (hoursUntil < 10) {
      hoursUntil = "0" + hoursUntil;
   }

   document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += " :" + hoursUntil + " hours";
}
```

Comment: Where is *dateObject* defined? Setting `Date.UTC(..., ..., ..., 0, 0, 0)` sets the UTC hour to 0, not 20 (8pm). `2880000` in ms represents .3 days. In seconds it represents 33.3 days. Neither are very accurate as approximations of the length of a month.

Comment: `... = daysUntil + " days";` should probably be `... += daysUntil + " days";`.

Comment: There are a huge number of duplicates, [*pick one*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%5Bdate%5D+difference+in+months+and+days).

Comment: You could just use moment.js library. It's pretty handy. 
https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var dateTo = Date.UTC(dateObject.getFullYear(), dateObject.getMonth(), 
                      dateObject.getDate(), 0, 0, 0); // all launches at 8:00pm UTC
```

to

```
var dateTo = ... dateObject.getDate (), 19, 0, 0;
```

Comment: sorry .. dateObject.getDate(), 19, 0, 0);